# How do I make a scope function work when using ng-include?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="keyboard.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab|Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="keyboard.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-include src="'keyboard.html'"></div>
        First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
        <br>
        Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
$scope.insertString = function(letter) {
        //$scope.name = $scope.name + letter;
        $scope.name = [$scope.name.slice(0,$scope.cursorPosVal),letter,$scope.name.slice($scope.cursorPosVal)].join('');
        console.log($scope.name);

        setTimeout(function(){ setCaretPosition("inputBox", $scope.cursorPosVal); }, 30);
    };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I know this is a bit thrown together, (the main code is just an example app from w3schools) but it shows what I am trying to do. So I have a keyboard app that I am bringing into the file (ng-include) and it appears absolutely wonderfully. My issue is that `$scope` is not being recognized. I have read the "Understanding Scopes" github document but it is just a bit much for me to take in. If someone could explain what I need to do to make sure that all of my `$scope` functions actually function, I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Your `$scope.insertString` seems to be outside the controller for some reason? Try moving it into the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Fissio said in the comments, you have a scope function declared outside of your controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
/**** see this here ****/
$scope.insertString = function(letter) {
        //$scope.name = $scope.name + letter;
        $scope.name = [$scope.name.slice(0,$scope.cursorPosVal),letter,$scope.name.slice($scope.cursorPosVal)].join('');
        console.log($scope.name);

        setTimeout(function(){ setCaretPosition("inputBox", $scope.cursorPosVal); }, 30);
    };
```

this is what you need:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "John";
        $scope.lastName = "Doe";
        $scope.insertString = function(letter) {
            //$scope.name = $scope.name + letter;
            $scope.name = [$scope.name.slice(0,$scope.cursorPosVal),letter,$scope.name.slice($scope.cursorPosVal)].join('');
            console.log($scope.name);

            setTimeout(function(){ setCaretPosition("inputBox", $scope.cursorPosVal); }, 30);
        };
    });
```

you can't use the keyword `$scope` outside of your controller because its bound to your controller. When it's outside angular will not know what it is that's why it will say something like it's not recognized

Comment: I've added the code into the right spot, and I am not getting errors, which I thank you for. For whatever reason it is not functioning still. Thank you for the help, i'm going to mess with this a little on my own to see if I can figure it out..

Comment: @abejdaniels I suggest you learn best practices with angular from the start. Here's a simple project I wrote to help get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/bn0Lxvwx/8/ . notice the different syntax and way to create controllers